# Packer instance accessing private Docker registry in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, docker, packer

With Jenkins, running in my **build** VPC, I've got a job that runs a Packer build to bake an AMI. During the AMI creation, I have to pull from my private Docker registry, also running in my **build** VPC.

I've got my registry locked right down, so it's only accessible from Jenkins or from my office.

When baking the AMI, I need to pull a docker image and start a container from it. However, because Packer's instance isn't permitted to access the registry, this fails.

I can't figure out how to dynamically allow access to the registry for this instance.

Is there a way to do this with Packer (or Jenkins), without having to have the registry wide open all the time?

Comment: Is there a tunnel between the office and the VPC?

Comment: No. I've got the office IP in a security group that's added to the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have Packer launch the instance being build into a security group using the settings: `security_group_id` or `security_groups_ids`. If you add that group to the security for the Docker Registry instance then communication should be allowed at the networking level. Permissions are all on you.

https://packer.io/docs/builders/amazon-ebs.html

Comment: Adding an SG to another SG only works on internal IPs though, right? I'm using an external IP address for my docker registry, so this won't work.
I'm going to try your suggested answer to my other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061542/packer-assign-specific-elastic-ip-to-instance

Comment: Ok, so you get the bounty because your answer to my other question fixed things. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There's a better way to do this (than I way I originally did it). If the private IP of your docker registry is fixed, which in my case it is, then you can write the private IP of your registry to the Packer Instance's /etc/hosts file, and map it to the normal DNS which has the SSL certificate assigned:

```echo '{{ user `docker_registry_ip` }} {{ user `docker_registry_host` }}' | sudo tee --append /etc/hosts```. Then you can use a self-referencing security group.