# Packer - Assign specific Elastic IP to instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

When I fire up an EC2 instance with Packer, in order to create an AMI, is there a way to assign it a **specific** elastic IP address, assuming I already own that IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Shell Provisioner](https://packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell.html)  to run a simple to script, uploaded with the [File Provisioner](https://packer.io/docs/provisioners/file.html) to your Packer instance. The script would utilize the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/associate-address.html) calling `associate-ipaddress` for this instance.

Comment: Aah... now I have a problem because the IP address changes, so Packer loses contact with the instance.

Comment: Fixed. Used 'ssh_private_ip' :)